# UISegmentedControl with tintColor doesn't show selection?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

Once you set the `tintColor` on a `UISegmentedControl` when it has a `segmentedControlStyle` of `UISegmentedControlStyleBar` it no longer shows which button you select. The valueChanged event still fires, but there isn't any color change in the selected button. Is there no way to show the selected button without leaving the control in the default blue style?

Answer (score 0):

if you set dark color as TintColor, you will not get selected effect, for that use light color like
put this code in change method of UISegmentControl

```
for (int i=0; i<[[sender subviews] count]; i++)
{
    if ([[[sender subviews] objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )
    {
        UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor redColor]; //your requiremnent color here
        [[[sender subviews] objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
        break;
    }
}
```

try this

Comment: dont set blackColor, otherwise you will face this problem.

Comment: actually i have selectedsegmentindex value and i want to set tint to green to selected index and grey to not selected index... but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Add Color for Selected Segment in `UISegmentcontrol`

here **sender** is `UISegmentControl`

```
for (int i=0; i<[sender.subviews count]; i++) 
{
    if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] ) 
    {               
    UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed:127.0/255.0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:183.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is working only in segmentchanged event, not when called manually from other method

Comment: get segmentcontrol by UISegmentedControl * sender = (UISegmentedControl *)Sg;